# Select rows where a column must have a same value for all rows

Tags: mysql

I want to write a MySQL script the accomplishes the following, I have an Orders table with data like this -

```
CustomerNumber | OrderNumber | Fullfilled
-----------------------------------------
001              10001         T
001              10002         T

002              10003         F
002              10004         T

003              10005         T
003              10006         T
003              10007         T

004              10008         T
```

I want to create a query that will list only the customer numbers that have more than 1 order, and *all* of their orders have Fullfilled = "T".

The query against the above data would result in a list of CustomerNumbers of - "001,003".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CustomerNumber 
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CustomerNumber 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1 AND SUM(Fullfilled <> 'T') = 0
```

The query uses two predicates in its `HAVING` clause:

- The first one returns customer numbers being related to more than one *distinct* order numbers
- The second one *filters out* customer numbers being related to *at least one* `Fullfilled = 'T'` record.

  [**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/KDR88091)

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
 select customerNumber from `table`
 group by customerNumber
 HAVING SUM(Fullfilled='T')>1
```

This code works as follows:

1- groups the costumer number with `group by customerNumber`

2- with `HAVING` and the aggregation function `SUM (Fullfilled = 'T')> 1` to filter by `customerNumber` that are repeated more than once.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CustomerNumber
FROM orders
GROUP BY Customernumber
HAVING Sum(Fullfilled = 'T') > 1
```

The above clause `HAVING Sum(Fullfilled = 'T') > 1` will ensure that only `customerNUmber` that have more than 1 `Fullfilled = 'T',` will be brought.
`GROUP BY` clause is used so as we can use the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this Select query to solve your problem

```
SELECT CustomerNumber FROM `Orders` WHERE Fullfilled = 'T' GROUP BY CustomerNumber, Fullfilled HAVING COUNT(CustomerNumber)>1;
```

The above clause `WHERE Fullfilled = 'T' GROUP BY CustomerNumber, Fullfilled` ensure that only `CustomerNumber` has `Fullfilled = 'T'` and `HAVING COUNT(CustomerNumber)>1` make sure that it has `OrderNumber > 1`

Comment: This page has useful information on the having clause https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
Select the customernumber from the orders table where fulfilled is set to T only.

Group it by the customernumber 

Having/Where the customernumber shows up more than once
```

Then the SQL is:

```
SELECT customernumber FROM orders 
WHERE fulfilled ='T'
GROUP BY customernumber 
HAVING 
COUNT(distinct customernumber) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`CustomerNumber` CHAR(3), `OrderNumber` INT, `Fullfilled` VARCHAR(1))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`CustomerNumber`, `OrderNumber`, `Fullfilled`)
VALUES
    ('001', 10001, 'T'),
    ('001', 10002, 'T'),
    ('002', 10003, 'F'),
    ('002', 10004, 'T'),
    ('003', 10005, 'T'),
    ('003', 10006, 'T'),
    ('003', 10007, 'T'),
    ('004', 10008, 'T')
;
```

What you want can be done with a combination off GROUP BY, COUNT and SUM. 
I will post some SELECTS with results so you can understand want is happping.

**Query**

```
SELECT
     CustomerNumber
   , COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1 #displays 1 if CustomerNummer has more than 1 unique OrderNumbers
   , SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') #SUM up if CustomerNumber if Fullfilled = 'T' is 1 (true)
   , SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) #displays 1 (true) if All records are Fullfilled = 'T' 
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY
  CustomerNumber
```

**Result**

```
CustomerNumber  COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1  SUM(Fullfilled = 'T')  SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber)  
--------------  -------------------------------  ---------------------  -----------------------------------------------------
001                                           1  2                                                                          1
002                                           1  1                                                                          0
003                                           1  3                                                                          1
004                                           0  1                                                                          1
```

Now to make sure to display only the records that have more the one order. 
We filter records out with `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1`

**Query**

```
SELECT
     CustomerNumber
   , COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1 #displays 1 if CustomerNummer has more than 1 unique OrderNumbers
   , SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') #SUM up if CustomerNumber if Fullfilled = 'T' is 1 (true)
   , SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) #display 1 if All records are Fullfilled = 'T'
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY
  CustomerNumber
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1
```

**Result**

```
CustomerNumber  COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1  SUM(Fullfilled = 'T')  SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber)  
--------------  -------------------------------  ---------------------  -----------------------------------------------------
001                                           1  2                                                                          1
002                                           1  1                                                                          0
003                                           1  3                                                                          1
```

Now to make sure to display only the records that have more the one order. 
And we make sure we filter out records that all the records should have Fullfilled = "T".
We filter records out with `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1 AND (SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) = 1)`

**Query**

```
SELECT
     CustomerNumber
   , COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1 #displays 1 if CustomerNummer has more than 1 unique OrderNumbers
   , SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') #SUM up if CustomerNumber if Fullfilled = 'T' is 1 (true)
   , SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) #display 1 if All records are Fullfilled = 'T'
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY
  CustomerNumber
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1
  AND
    (SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) = 1)
```

**Result**

```
CustomerNumber  COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1  SUM(Fullfilled = 'T')  SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber)  
--------------  -------------------------------  ---------------------  -----------------------------------------------------
001                                           1  2                                                                          1
003                                           1  3                                                                          1
```

**Final query**

```
SELECT
  CustomerNumber
FROM 
 t
GROUP BY
  CustomerNumber
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) > 1
  AND
    (SUM(Fullfilled = 'T') = COUNT(DISTINCT OrderNumber) = 1)
```

**Result**

```
CustomerNumber  
----------------
001             
003
```